# Data structure that returns index and stores count of strings in c++

Tags: c++, xml, data-structures, xlsx

I am building an xlsx builder, and I have a series of strings to save in a spreadsheet (xml file). There may be duplication, so I want to store the strings in a map and increment their counts. Then instead of storing the strings I can store the index they are at in the map, and store the strings in another xml file. But retrieving the index of a given string is O(n) with std::map. Is there a data structure that can accomplish this faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your "separate file" needs to be in lexicographic order don't use the index in the map, store the index explicitly.

So for example a `map<string, gubbins>`, with `struct gubbins { size_t count; size_t index; }`.

Whenever you insert a new key to the map, give its index the "next" value of an incrementing counter.

The range of index values used is contiguous *unless* you later come along and decrement the refcount then remove entries from the map when it hits zero. In that case you can "defragment" the indexes, but of course not if you've already used the indexes to identify the strings elsewhere.

The operation to write the strings file requires sorting by index first. You can do that in linear time -- create a big enough array and then run through the map, storing each string at the correct index. Or you can build the strings file as you go, adding each string when it's added to the map.

It's probably possible to do the whole thing with the right `boost:multi_index`.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but since the std::map stores keys in ascending order, I assumed the OP needed indices to correspond to the sorted ordering of the strings rather than the insertion ordering.  Would this work in that scenario?

Comment: I only need the index to be fixed once the string has been inserted once. So this solution will work fine. I never remove a string from it .

Comment: @templatetypedef: I've just edited to that effect -- I'm assuming the the purpose is *solely* to avoid duplication, and therefore that there's no requirement for the indexes to relate to the string sort order. If that assumption's wrong, the answer doesn't help.

Comment: Of course I have to check for existence of a given string before inserting now which is log(n), but that's ok

Comment: @ravloony: you could use an `unordered_map` instead of a `map`, since the lexicographical order is irrelevant to everything.

Comment: @ravloony: usually. You can have an argument about whether hashtables are "really" worst-case-constant-time lookup, but that argument revolves in part around the computation model used for the analysis so it's quite hair-splitty. For practical purposes, if you have a decent hash function then hashtables have constant-time lookup. The thing about the map is that it does `O(log n)` string comparisons, and each string comparison's cost depends on the length of the common initial segment of the strings. So naturally the last few comparisons in a `map<string, T>` lookup will be slowish.

Comment: @ravloony: out of interest, if you never decrement the refcount then what do you actually need to know it for?

Comment: @SteveJessop : Basically I keep a count of all strings as I build the excel file, and replace them with a number. So the first string I replace with 0, the second with 1 etc. But if for example a string is a duplicate of the first one, I replace it with 0. Then after having built my worksheet, I build the strings file, which needs to follow that same numbering scheme. So when the file is read, the parser sees [type=string, index=0], and fetches the first string from the strings file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the strings in sorted order, you might want to look into the [order statistic tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) data structure, which is a balanced binary search tree augmented with extra information that makes it possible to determine the nth element in the tree efficiently (in O(log n) time).  This gives you all of the original functionality of the `std::map`, plus random access.

There isn't a standard implementation of order statistic trees in the C++ standard libraries, but a quick Google search should turn some up.

Hope this helps!